ClosedXML add at (@) symbol at formulas
I have to edit an excel file with C#, I am using ClosedXML library. I have the following formula in my C# code.
string fxRateFormula = $"=IFERROR(INDEX('Control Tab'!$E$2:$E$157,MATCH($B5&"|"&"USD",'Control Tab'!$A$2:$A$157&"|"&'Control Tab'!$B$2:$B$157,0))*IF(C5="USD",1,INDEX('Control Tab'!$E$2:$E$157,MATCH($C5&"|"&"USD",'Control Tab'!$A$2:$A$157&"|"&'Control Tab'!$B$2:$B$157,0))),"")";
fxWorksheet.Cells(fxRateCurrentCell).FormulaA1 = fxRateFormula;
Why when saving the excel and then opening the file, the formula has at (@) symbols in it?
=IFERROR(INDEX('Control Tab'!$E$2:$E$157,MATCH($B5&"|"&"USD",@'Control Tab'!$A$2:$A$157&"|"&@'Control Tab'!$B$2:$B$157,0))*IF(C5="USD",1,INDEX('Control Tab'!$E$2:$E$157,MATCH($C5&"|"&"USD",@'Control Tab'!$A$2:$A$157&"|"&@'Control Tab'!$B$2:$B$157,0))),"")
